# java facebook api - callback feature for removing an app from user's account

Tags: facebook

Is there any facebook API that can make a call to my server when a user removes an application from his/her account?

I want my application to be notified when a user removes my facebook application from his/her account.

I am just wondering if facebook provides this kind of feature.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook provides this feature.

Go to http://developers.facebook.com/apps
Edit Your App
Go to Settings > Advanced
Look for `Deauthorise Callback URL:` in the authentication panel.